# How to find and start the first job in programming?

Tags: windows, unix

I do have some background in programming but only at home not at work.  How to look and start for a first job in programming?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question as defined in the Help Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can try to find programmer jobs at startups online. LinkedIn, AngelList are some good platforms to find jobs at startup. Even in StackOverflow, you will see job circulars too. Apply to them if you think you are fulfilling their requirements. Make a good portfolio with your projects on which you have worked so that the hiring authority can check your programming projects. Mostly, entry-level programming jobs have assessment tests. If you can crack those assessment tests at the beginning, you will be selected for the further steps in the recruitment process.

**You can check these sites:**

[LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/)

[AngelList](https://angel.co/jobs)